# Getting Count from Grouped DataTable in VB via Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I'm running into a mental roadblock here and I'm hoping that I'm missing something obvious.

Anyway, assume I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID            LookupValue         SortOrder
============================================
1             A                   1000
2             B                   2000
3             B                   2000
4             C                   3000
5             C                   4000
```

I'm trying to find, using Linq, places where the `LookupValue` is the same, but the sort order is different (the `ID` is a PK on my Database table and is irrelevant to this exercise).

I thought the easiest way would be to group by the `LookupValue` and the `SortOrder` and then find places where the `LookupValue` appears more than twice in the result.

Right now, my code to get the grouped table looks like this:

```
Dim KeySortPairs = From d In MyDataTable _
            Group By Key = d(LookupValue).ToString(), SortOrder = d(SortOrder).ToString() _
            Into Group _
            Select Key, SortOrder
```

Looking in the debug output, the above code produces this result (which is correct):

```
Key    SortOrder
================
A      1000
B      2000
C      3000
C      4000
```

To get the duplicate `Key`'s then, I'm looking through the results like this:

```
For Each Entry In KeySortPairs.Where(Function(t) t.Key.Count() > 1)
    'Multiple Sort Orders!!'
Next
```

In this code, however, *every* entry in the grouped result gets returned.  Am I missing something, or shouldn't that count only give me the entries where the `Key` appears more than once?  I assume I'm making a trivial mistake due to my low-level of comfort with VB.NET, but I can't figure it out -- I've tried moving the `Count()` into a `WHERE` clause on the Linq expression, but that gave me the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key is a string.

Key.Count counts the characters in the string.

---

Change the select to include the group

```
Select Key, SortOrder, Group
```

and change the where clause to count the group

```
KeySortPairs.Where(Function(t) t.Group.Count() > 1)
```

Alternatively, counting the group might be overkill.  "Any" can save time by doing a short enumeration.

```
KeySortPairs.Where(Function(t) t.Group.Skip(1).Any())
```

(syntax might not be perfect, I don't know vb.linq).

Comment: Ah, duh!  That explains why t.Key.Count() > 7 (a test I was trying) was returning no results!

Comment: Also, counting the group doesn't seem to be working.  Logically I'm not sure it makes sense either since by definition, the group by will only return one unique Key, SortOrder pair -- correct?

Comment: Groups in linq are hierarchical, unlike SQL.  A group has a key and one or more child elements.  These elements can be accessed by enumerating the group.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a groupby in your for each statement.

Try something like

```
For Each Entry in KeySortPairs.GroupBy(expression).Where(
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really old question. I was just trying out. Initially wrote solution in C# and converted to VB.NET by some online converter. Hope doesn't offend any one.

```
 Dim tests As New List(Of test)() From { _
            New test() With { _
                Key.LookUp = "A", _
                Key.SortOrder1 = 1000 _
            }, _
            New test() With { _
                Key.LookUp = "B", _
                Key.SortOrder1 = 2000 _
            }, _
            New test() With { _
                Key.LookUp = "B", _
                Key.SortOrder1 = 2000 _
            }, _
            New test() With { _
                Key.LookUp = "C", _
                Key.SortOrder1 = 3000 _
            }, _
            New test() With { _
                Key.LookUp = "C", _
                Key.SortOrder1 = 4000 _
            } _
        }

  Dim query = From g In From t In testsGroup t By t.LookUpLet firstsortorder = g.First() Where g.Count() > 1 AndAlso g.Any(Function(t1) firstsortorder.SortOrder1 <> t1.SortOrder1)New With { _
  g.Key, _
  Key .result = g _
}

    For Each item As var In query
        Console.WriteLine("key " + item.Key)
        For Each item1 As var In item.result
            Console.WriteLine(vbTab & vbTab & "sort order " + item1.SortOrder1)
        Next
    Next
```